# EWS Managed APIs in iOS

Tags: ios7, ios6, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm developing an iOS app where it requires to use EWS managed APIs. I've searched the web thoroughly but I'm not getting any success.

It requires to get and set user's profile information, i.e. User's display name, company name, phone number etc.

Answer (score 5):

EWS Managed API is for Windows desktop apps only. You can use Exchange Web Service SOAP endpoint directly. Although it will be little tedious to handle xml based requests/responses but do-able. Take a look at this channel9 talk: [Developing Mobile Apps with Microsoft Exchange Web Services](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/OUC-B304#fbid=)

Edit: I don't have any personal experience of getting iOS app to work with EWS though, but I'm pretty confident that it should work. Also, I guess you will need Exchange Server to support Basic Auth which is the case with Exchange Online but not sure about On-Premise(and it's variants). If link provided above is not up anymore, my recommendation is to just follow Exchange Web Services documentation from Microsoft (**not** Exchange Managed API)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I think essential part of my answer is to directly work with Exchange Web Service which has nothing special than any other SOAP based service. Made few edits though on re-consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use Xamarin. With Xamarin we use [Exchange Web Services .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/index.html). It is commercial API, but works great.

Comment: Have your read previous answer before posting your one? It's about the same, and it was not accepted.