# How to access exchange server from Xcode or Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, exchangewebservices

I am experiencing problems in Xamarin when I use EWS Managed API 1.2. Everything is working in debug mode but I cannot compile to publish in app store. I have an 'error MT2002: failure to resolve assembly: 'System.Security ...'

Any suggestion to connect to exchange server from Xcode or Xamarin project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506891/ews-managed-apis-in-ios/26082907#26082907 - Xamarin solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).  You've already tagged the question with EWS, so I'm not sure what different answer you are expecting?

Here is a TechEd session on using EWS from iOS: [Developing Mobile Apps with Microsoft Exchange Web Services](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/OUC-B304#fbid=)